# Why are options missing from my Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise?

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, visual-studio-2015

I can't find the Memory or Registers windows in the Debug menu -> Windows

Any idea as to why this could be?

I have them when I use my computers at school, but those  are running the Community Version Of VS2015 and at home I run Enterprise. Could that be it? Is it fixable?

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

In the screenshot you can see I am in "Debugging mode", so that's not it. And some window options are missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone comes here for a solution, here is the answer from the requester itself:

> the address-level debugging option should be enabled

References:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62680774.aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439506(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: This is better than the first answer you gave (which was removed for being a link only answer). You quoted a relevant part this time. Previously you actually had to go to the links to see the solution.